# Checking Column in Matrix for Duplicate and Performing a Number Switch - Sudoku - Python

Tags: python, loops, duplicates, sudoku

So I'm doing this as a personal project and I'm having some difficulty getting the result I am looking for.

```
def createSudoku():
    rowCount = 9
    columnCount = 9
    gameBoard = []

    ##Row entry is randomized order
    ##Column entry is not randomized order
    ##Row entry cannot be duplicate
    for row in range(rowCount):
        rowList = []
        sudokuNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        for column in range(columnCount):
            choice = random.choice(sudokuNumbers)
            rowList.append(choice)
            sudokuNumbers.remove(choice)
        gameBoard.append(rowList)
```

So, the above portion of my code is current creating my rows at random, which was my intention. Right now, I'm beginning to search through the matrix with another loop to discern the columns are actually random.

```
    K = 0
    ##Column Duplicate Algorithm
    while(K < columnCount):
        for sub in gameBoard:
            columnK = sub[K]
        sudokuNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        for item in range(columnK):
            if item in sudokuNumbers:
                sudokuNumbers.remove(item)
            else:
                sub.append(sub.pop(sub.index(item)))
                if ...            

        K += 1
```

My intention for the column search is to utilize the column's position [item] with the row location [K] and to either pop/move another entry on that row in place of the duplicate, recheck, and continue. The issue I am now seeing after I was tinkering with it, was that my initial thoughts are to use a loop or perform it recursively, but that would be a pretty big rabbit hole. I'm curious to my options in this situation to determine how to replace the entry on the row, or am I over-complicating the resolution here?

I understand that what I should focus on for better OOP is to seperate the loops as their own functions and it's my intention to do so, I'm just getting stuck on this check for my Sudoku.

Answer (score 0):

This loop will find a duplicates for you and vanish it.

```
exclusions = [43606,125490,...]
def ID_Generator(new_clients): # This is a list of new client

  new_client_IDs = []

  while len(new_client_IDs) < len(new_clients):
    ID = randint(40000, 200000)
    if ID not in exclusions:
      new_client_IDs.append(ID)
    if list(dict.fromkeys(new_client_IDs)):

      new_client_IDs = list(dict.fromkeys(new_client_IDs))
```